# Bitcoin Core What default values should I pass for some positional RPC params in sendtoaddress

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I am trying to use the `sendtoaddress` rpc method of bitcoin core. From the [documentation](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/wallet/sendtoaddress/) I read that I can pass `"estimate_mode"` parameter to estimate a fee. However as I believe json rpc follows positional parameters, so this parameter falls in the 8th position, before this there is another optional parameter named `"conf_target"`. What value should I pass for this parameter?

```
bitcoin-cli bchtest:qp4uw0why90dht7texkv3nnws4cjml844y5ck8rr3q  0.1 "" "" false false ? "CONSERVATIVE"
```

What value should I pass in place of `'?'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fee estimator works by targeting the number of blocks that will occur between the time when you broadcast and when it confirms. So a confirmation target of 6 would mean that the fee estimator is trying to get your transaction confirmed within 6 blocks. The fee estimator does not know within how many blocks you want your transaction to be confirmed, so it asks you as a parameter.

The default value for this is 6, but you can set it to whatever you want.